# React-Redux: Copying an array from the state in Reducer function so that you can modify it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a React application and I am using Redux to store the state. I have the following code:

menu.reducer.js:

```
import { INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK } from './menu.types';

const INITIAL_STATE = []


export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK: {
            console.log("Printing the state");
            console.log(state);
            return state.map(category => {
                if (category._id === action.payload._id) {
                    const oldrank = category.rank;
                    return {
                        ...category,
                        rank: oldrank + 1
                    }
                } else {
                    return category;
                }
            })
        }
        case DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK: {
            return state.map(category => {
                if (category._id === action.payload._id && category.rank !== -1) {
                    const oldrank = category.rank;
                    return {
                        ...category,
                        rank: oldrank - 1
                    }
                } else {
                    return category;
                }
            })
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

menu.types.js:

```
export const INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK = "INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK";
export const DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK = "DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK";
```

menu.actions.js:

```
import { apiUrl, apiConfig } from '../../util/api';
import { INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK } from './menu.types';

export const getMenu = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/menu`);
    if (response.ok) {
        const menuData = await response.json();
        dispatch({ type: GET_MENU, payload: menuData })
    }
}

export const increaseCategoryRank = category => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, payload: category })
}

export const decreaseCategoryRank = category => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: DECREASE_CATEGORY_RANK, payload: category })
}
```

category-arrows.component.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { increaseCategoryRank, decreaseCategoryRank } from '../../redux/menu/menu.actions';
import './category-arrows.styles.scss';

class CategoryArrows extends Component {

    render() {

        const { category, increaseCategoryRank, decreaseCategoryRank } = this.props;

        return (
            <div class="arrows-container">
                <div class="up-arrow" onClick={() => this.props.increaseCategoryRank(category)}></div>
                <div class="category-rank">
                    <p>{category.rank}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="down-arrow" onClick={() => this.props.decreaseCategoryRank(category)}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, { increaseCategoryRank, decreaseCategoryRank } )(CategoryArrows);
```

For my Reducer function, the initial state is retrieved from a database. The Reducer code deals with the `menu` array, which is an array of objects:

[image]

I want to sort this `menu` array with respect to the `rank` property value, and also swap elements in the array based on certain conditions. To do this, I have to copy the array first, make the modifications and then reassign the state to this new array.

I have tried to console.log() the state to see what it is in my Reducer function. When I click on the `up-arrow` div in `category-arrows.component.jsx`, the `INCREASE_CATEGORY_RANK` action is dispatched. When I check the Console, I get the following:

[image]

I am not sure how to copy the menu array from the state in my Reducer function so that I can make the modifications that I want to and then reassign this array to the state. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Are you simply just trying to do more changes in the reducer where you map state already? Like you want to do the sorting in the reducer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy an array without mutating the original (assuming this is a reducer case):

```
// make a copy of the original
const updatedArray = [...state.menu]

// find the object you want to modify (this is a generic example)
let selectedItem = updatedArray.findIndex((element) => {
  return element.id === action.payload._id
}

// make your modification (let's pretend you wanted to update the name property)
updatedArray[selectedItem].name = 'Changed Name'

// merge the original state and set the menu property to the updatedArray
return {
  ...state,
  menu: updatedArray
}
```

Is this the problem you're trying to solve (copying original state and modifying it)?

Comment: I have a similare Problem, but your solution is not solving it. Following code

on(selectWorkflow, (state, {workflowStep, workflowSubstep, viewMode}) => {
    const original = state.workflowModel.stepList
    const stepsCopy = [...original]
    stepsCopy.map(step => step.selected = false)  
    return {...state, stepList: stepsCopy, workflowStep, workflowSubstep, viewMode}

Leads to the error message: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '[object Object]'